# Calculate max min distance of pointclouds's in overlapping area

Tags: python, python-3.x, point-clouds

Testing different methods of pointclouds' registrations and trying to do different evaluations on the results.

One of the evaluations is trying to find the overlap area between the two pointclouds and calculating the max min distance of each one of the pointcloud's points against the other overlapping pointcloud's points.

So far I have worked naively with the following steps (assume two PCs):

1. Find bounding box for each of the two clouds. Simply using
   `min(pc1X)`, `min(pc1Y)` . . .
2. Find the overlapping areas of the boxes. (max of mins, min of maxs of box's coordinates.)
3. Extract each of the cloud's points within the box. Also naive filtering. `pc1[x<xmax & x>xmin & y<...]`
4. Calculate distance cost matrix between the points and pick min for each point. Cost matrix shape: `(pc1_pnts x pc2_pnts)`. Using `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`  `

This works fine for small clouds, however when overlap area gets bigger, out of memory error is experienced, which had to happen at some point using the above steps, especially on step 4.

Hence I'm looking for options to improve the above steps in order to run them on bigger clouds, I believe the most crucial bottleneck here is step 4 where the cost matrix could get huge.

I would appreciate tips on improving the first three steps, but focusing on step 4, how could the max min distance of each of the overlapping points be calculated more efficiently?

---

EDIT: By using `sklearn.neighbours.NearestNeighbors` I've managed to reduce the runtime of step 4 by more than 10x on average and also run on bigger clouds!
Still any tips or leads to improve any of the above steps are welcomed.